why dotnet-csharpier is not using DOTNET_ROOT variable?
I have this dotnet version with these runtimes and sdk's
.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   6.0.423
 Commit:    c5c9e53229

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     linuxmint
 OS Version:  21.3
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         linux-x64
 Base Path:   /home/gonzalo/dotnet/sdk/6.0.423/

global.json file:
  Not found

Host:
  Version:      6.0.31
  Architecture: x64
  Commit:       e2ca2f8a1c

.NET SDKs installed:
  6.0.423 [/home/gonzalo/dotnet/sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.31 [/home/gonzalo/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.31 [/home/gonzalo/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

Download .NET:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

Learn about .NET Runtimes and SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/runtimes-sdk-info


And this is the output for DOTNET_ROOT
/home/gonzalo/dotnet

But I get this error when trying to run dotnet-csharpier .
You must install .NET to run this application.

App: /home/gonzalo/.dotnet/tools/dotnet-csharpier
Architecture: x64
App host version: 6.0.31
.NET location: Not found

Learn about runtime installation:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed

Download the .NET runtime:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?missing_runtime=true&arch=x64&rid=linuxmint.21.3-x64&apphost_version=6.0.31


The command only works when I do a symlink of /home/gonzalo/dotnet to /usr/lib/dotnet, but why is not using the DOTNET_ROOT path
I tried searching for documentation in the dotnet-csharpier documentation, maybe I didn't look in the right place, but I just couldn't find anything.
